# C++ Beginner: Minor Issues with Functions

Tags: c++, function

I just started learning C++ and coming from no tech experience whatsoever, so please be patient with me! Im using Codecademy to learn and encountered an issue with one of the exercises. I tried to create this function to remove repeating code in `main()`.

```
#include <iostream>
std::string on_off_attempt;
std::string IT_support(){
  std::cout << "Hello. IT\n";
  std::cout << "Have you tried turning it off and on again? y/ n\n";
  std::cin >> on_off_attempt;
  if (on_off_attempt == "y"){
    std::cout << "It should be working now!\n";
  }
  else if (on_off_attempt == "n"){
   std::cout << "Then please try again!\n";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Invalid Input!\n";
    std::cin >> on_off_attempt;
  }
  return on_off_attempt;
  }
```

As far as the first input, it works fine, but on the next input prompt, it no longer acknowledges the input for `on_off_attempt` and immediately just goes to the next output line. Below is the `main()` code.

```
int main() {

  // Conduct IT support
  IT_support();

  // Check in with Jenn
  std::cout << "Oh hi Jen!\n";

  // Conduct IT support again...
 IT_support();

  // Check in with Roy
  std::cout << "You stole the stress machine? But that's stealing!\n";

  // Conduct IT support yet again...zzzz...
  IT_support();
}
```

Could anyone tell me what Im doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you want to re-enter on_off_attempt if the user enters an invalid input?

Comment: please include the input and output. Invalid input could cause a problem, but otherwise the code looks ok

Comment: When you say 'first input', do you mean the first call to `IT_support()`, or the first call to `cin`?

Comment: Hi @Roy2511 Yes, that and also for the second and third times the function is executed. On the 2nd and 3rd `cin`, it no longer responds to a y/n input.

Comment: Hi @melk ! I meant the first call to `cin`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it goes directly to the next output line is because you never tell it to keep asking for input until it gets a valid one. You need a loop for that. Something like this:

```
std::string IT_support(){
  std::string on_off_attempt;
  bool inputValid = false;
  std::cout << "Hello. IT\n";
  std::cout << "Have you tried turning it off and on again? y/ n\n";
  while (!inputValid) {
    std::cin >> on_off_attempt;
    if (on_off_attempt == "y"){
      std::cout << "It should be working now!\n";
      inputValid = true;
    }
    else if (on_off_attempt == "n"){
      std::cout << "Then please try again!\n";
      inputValid = true;
    }
    else {
      std::cout << "Invalid Input!\n";
      inputValid = false;
    }
  }
  return on_off_attempt;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see it now! Thank you so so much for the help! :)